# Weighted covariance in R (cov.wt) doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: r, covariance, weighted

A minimal reproducible example (with a one-column matrix, where covariance matrix reduces to variance):

```
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:2), c(1,3))$cov
var(c(1, 2, 2, 2))
```

It seems to be a bug, because I think `cov.wt` doesn't even use the `weights` argument:

```
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:2), c(1,30))$cov
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:2), c(10,3))$cov
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:2), c(10,30))$cov
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:2), c(123,987))$cov
```

Comment: try to make bigger matrices like this : `cov.wt(as.matrix(1:4), c(1,30,5:6))$cov
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:4), c(10,3,7:8))$cov
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:4), c(10,30,9:10))$cov
cov.wt(as.matrix(1:4), c(123,987,11:12))$cov` then you can see it will use the weights

Comment: so I think (but would have to double check) that a one column matrix is a vector and that might influence how the weights are used (or if they are used at all)

Comment: @Mike OK, but it is still strange (bug?) that it doesn't work for vectors of length 2, only for 4. Also `cov.wt(as.matrix(1:4), c(1,30,5:6))$cov` gives 1.25, but `var(var(rep(1:4,c(1,30,5:6)))` is 0.583, so it - even if uses the weights - gives incorrect answer.

Comment: @Mike No, `is.matrix(as.matrix(1:2))` is TRUE, so technically it is a matrix.